# Debug Python Unit Tests in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: python, unit-testing, cloud9

Can anyone tell me how to interactively run and debug python unit tests in the Cloud9 IDE?

I would like to run & debug my python unit tests in the Cloud9 IDE similar to the same process using the JetBrains Pycharm IDE. Debugging in this context is running single or multiple unit tests, setting breakpoints, stepping though code, examining variables as well as user input expressions.

I've looked at run configurations in Cloud9, but I could find no clear options on how to interactively run & debug unit tests in the Cloud9 IDE.